# Can I use Dlib for Track pupil of eyes?

Tags: opencv, dlib

I am doing project on driver drowsiness detection system,I have used Opencv face and eye detection.Now I need to track eye pupils.Can I use dlib for the same,or is there any algorithm which will give me accurate pupil tracking.

Please help

Comment: Check out this: [https://github.com/aashish-bth/Drowsiness-Detection-System](https://github.com/aashish-bth/Drowsiness-Detection-System)

Comment: @Aashish This is not pupil tracking.

Answer (score 0):

You can basically track anything using dlib's correlation tracker: 
http://dlib.net/correlation_tracker.py.html

Speaking about gaze you are probably going to have an easier time using something like PyGaze:
https://github.com/esdalmaijer/PyGaze

Hope it helps